# How can I transform this array of my database to this using Rxjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

How can I transform this array of my database to this using Rxjs. I need to groupBy the key

```
[
  { date: 'mydate',
  exam: {
    hb: 10,
    ht: 30,
    plq: 250,
    cr: 1.2
  }},
  { date: 'mydate1',
    exam: {
      hb: 13,
      tap: 1,
      plq: 210,
      ck: 300
    }}
];
```

to this (I need group by each key of exam's and separate the multiple values with their dates when it occurs):

```
[
  {
    exam: 'hb',
    regs: [
      {date: 'mydate1', value: 10},
      {date: 'mydate2', value: 13}
    ]
  },
  {
    exam: 'ht',
    regs: [
      {data: 'mydate1', value: 30},
    ]
  },
  {
    exam: 'plq',
    regs: [
      {date: 'mydate1', value: 250},
      {date: 'mydate2', value: 210},
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: what have you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce`, `object#keys` and `array#forEach`. Iterate through your array and for all the keys in `exam` create an object and for the duplicate key push value in the array. Then extract the values using `Object.values()`

```js
var data = [ { date: 'mydate', exam: { hb: 10, ht: 30, plq: 250, cr: 1.2 }}, { date: 'mydate1', exam: { hb: 13, tap: 1, plq: 210, ck: 300 }} ],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,{date, exam}) => {
      Object.keys(exam).forEach(k => {
        r[k] = r[k] || {exam : k , regs : []};
        r[k].regs.push({date, value: exam[k]})
      });
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```